# Switching between Terminal tabs in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Got several Terminal tabs in IDE. If i right-click any of them i see that i can switch between tabs using Alt+Right and Alt+Left:

[image]

However, these combinations don't seem to work. Using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 Community Edition  
P.S. Switching between editor tabs works fine with the same combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200854) in 2018.3 release, it will be fixed in 2018.3.1 update.

As a workaround you can disable [the option to override IDE shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Ty8.png).